# Calculate percentage Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, parameter-passing, percentage

I have a question about javascript logic what I use to get percent of two inputs from my text fields. Here is my code:

```
    var pPos = $('#pointspossible').val();
    var pEarned = $('#pointsgiven').val();
    
    var perc = ((pEarned/pPos) * 100).toFixed(3);
    $('#pointsperc').val(perc);
```

For some reason if my inputs are 600 and 200, my result suppose to be  33.333 but I'm getting 3.333. If I hard code my values this works fine. If anyone can help I appreciate that.

Comment: are you sure pPos and pEarned are those values?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It seems working :

HTML :

```
 <input type='text' id="pointspossible"/>
<input type='text' id="pointsgiven" />
<input type='text' id="pointsperc" disabled/>
```

JavaScript :

```
    $(function(){

    $('#pointspossible').on('input', function() {
      calculate();
    });
    $('#pointsgiven').on('input', function() {
     calculate();
    });
    function calculate(){
        var pPos = parseInt($('#pointspossible').val()); 
        var pEarned = parseInt($('#pointsgiven').val());
        var perc="";
        if(isNaN(pPos) || isNaN(pEarned)){
            perc=" ";
           }else{
           perc = ((pEarned/pPos) * 100).toFixed(3);
           }

        $('#pointsperc').val(perc);
    }

});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/vikashvverma/1khs8sj7/1/

Comment: What if values are empty?

Comment: for that you need to check first. I have just given you a POC that it works.

Comment: I had that already. I do not need hard coded values. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Then how you are getting value 3.333?

Comment: I do not know, that's the issue. I'm passing entered values from input field and I'm getting that output.

Comment: Do you know how to reset this function every time after I click on my input text field? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80929/discussion-between-vikash-and-user3023588).

Answer (score 128):

You can use this

```
function percentage(partialValue, totalValue) {
   return (100 * partialValue) / totalValue;
}
```

Example to calculate the percentage of a course progress base in their activities.

```
const totalActivities = 10;
const doneActivities = 2;

percentage(doneActivities, totalActivities) // Will return 20 that is 20%
```

Comment: Just a note: this will return `NaN` if `partialValue = 0` and `totalValue  = 0`

Answer (score 27):

Try:

```js
const result = Math.round((data.expense / data.income) * 100)
```

Answer (score 17):

To get the percentage of a number, we need to multiply the desired percentage **percent** by that **number**. In practice we will have:

```
function percentage(percent, total) {
    return ((percent/ 100) * total).toFixed(2)
}
```

Example of usage:

```
const percentResult = percentage(10, 100);
// print 10.00
```

`.toFixed()` is optional for monetary formats.

Comment: A bit condescending for an answer.

Comment: toFixed() will type case the value into a string.

Comment: @jefelewis: You can wrap the result into a Number() call and get a number back, removing trailing zeroes.

Answer (score 5):

Cool (unreadable) oneliner:

```js
const percentage = ~~((pointsGiven / pointsPossible) * 100);
```

`~~` is the same as `Math.round()`

Try it:

```js
const pointsPossible = 600;
const pointsGiven = 200;

const percentage = ~~((pointsGiven / pointsPossible) * 100);

console.log(`Percentage: %${percentage}`)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var number = 5000;
var percentX = 12;
var result;

function percentCalculation(a, b){
  var c = (parseFloat(a)*parseFloat(b))/100;
  return parseFloat(c);
}

result = percentCalculation(number, percentX); //calculate percentX% of number
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```js
function percent(quantity, percent)
{
    return (quantity * percent) / 100;
}

   console.log(percent(40,10))
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. He's trying to get the percentage difference between 2 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Heres another approach.

**HTML:**

```
<input type='text' id="pointspossible" class="clsInput" />
<input type='text' id="pointsgiven"  class="clsInput" />
<button id="btnCalculate">Calculate</button>
<input type='text' id="pointsperc" disabled/>
```

**JS Code:**

```
function isNumeric(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}


$('#btnCalculate').on('click', function() {
    var a = $('#pointspossible').val().replace(/ +/g, "");
    var b = $('#pointsgiven').val().replace(/ +/g, "");
    var perc = "0";
    if (a.length > 0 && b.length > 0) {
        if (isNumeric(a) && isNumeric(b)) {
            perc = a / b * 100;
        }
    }    
    $('#pointsperc').val(perc).toFixed(3);
});
```

Live Sample: [Percentage Calculator](http://percentagecalculation.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function calculate() {
    // amount
        var salary = parseInt($('#salary').val());
    // percent    
        var incentive_rate = parseInt($('#incentive_rate').val());
        var perc = "";
        if (isNaN(salary) || isNaN(incentive_rate)) {
            perc = " ";
        } else {
            perc =  (incentive_rate/100) * salary;
          

        } $('#total_income').val(perc);
    }
```

Comment: Please give some explanation

Answer (score 0):

For percent increase and decrease, using 2 different methods:

```js
const a = 541
const b = 394

// Percent increase 
console.log(
  `Increase (from ${b} to ${a}) => `,
  (((a/b)-1) * 100).toFixed(2) + "%",
)

// Percent decrease
console.log(
  `Decrease (from ${a} to ${b}) => `,
  (((b/a)-1) * 100).toFixed(2) + "%",
)

// Alternatives, using .toLocaleString() 
console.log(
  `Increase (from ${b} to ${a}) => `,
  ((a/b)-1).toLocaleString('fullwide', {maximumFractionDigits:2, style:'percent'}),
)

console.log(
  `Decrease (from ${a} to ${b}) => `,
  ((b/a)-1).toLocaleString('fullwide', {maximumFractionDigits:2, style:'percent'}),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id="contentse "><br>
      <h2>Percentage Calculator</h2>
    <form action="/charactercount" class="align-items-center" style="border: 1px solid #eee;padding:15px;" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form">
        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="NCBdw9beXfKV07Tc1epTBPqJ0gzfkmHNXKrAauE34n3jn4TGeL8Vv6miOShhqv6O">
        <div style="border: 0px solid white;color:#eee;padding:5px;width:900px">
        <br><div class="input-float" style="float: left;"> what is <input type="text" id="aa" required=""> % of <input type="text" id="ab"> ? </div><div class="output-float"><input type="button" class="crm-submit" value="calculate" onclick="calculatea()"> &nbsp; <input type="text" id="ac" readonly="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div><br style="clear: both;"> </div><br>
        <hr><br>
        
        <div style="border: 0px solid white;color:#eee;padding:5px;width:900px">
        <div class="input-float" style="float: left;"><input type="text" id="ba"> is what percent of <input type="text" id="bb"> ? </div><div class="output-float"><input type="button" class="crm-submit" value="calculate" onclick="calculateb()"> &nbsp; <input type="text" id="bc" readonly=""> &nbsp; % </div><br style="clear: both;"></div><br>
        <hr><br>
        
        <div style="border: 0px solid white;color:#eee;padding:5px;width:900px">
        Find percentage change(increase/decrease) <br><br>
        <div class="input-float" style="float: left;">from <input type="text" id="ca"> to <input type="text" id="cb">&nbsp;?  </div><div class="output-float"><input type="button" class="crm-submit" value="calculate" onclick="calculatec()"> &nbsp; <input type="text" id="cc" readonly="">&nbsp;%</div><br style="clear: both;"></div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Live example here: [setool-percentage-calculator](https://online-se-tools.herokuapp.com/percentage-calculator?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=post)

Answer (score 0):

how to calculate percentage with return

```js
function sum (a,b){
 let s = a+b
 return s;
 }
 
 let total= sum(20,20)
 percentage(total);
 
 function percentage(t){
 let per = t/200*100;
 document.write(per);
 }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

try

```
var result = (35.8 / 100) * 10;
```

Thanks

Comment: @BrunoQuaresma but its worked well for me for one calculation purpose.

Comment: This is static formula and we cannot relay on static things in development.

Comment: you should share general formula not static values.